# How to do JSONParsing in typescript

Tags: android, json, angular, typescript

I know jsonparsing in Android.
if below is the JSON Response

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },

  ]
}
```

We used to get data from the response like this

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");


                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString("id");
                            String name = c.getString("name");
                            String email = c.getString("email");
                            String address = c.getString("address");
                            String gender = c.getString("gender");

                            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                            String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                            String home = phone.getString("home");
                            String office = phone.getString("office");
}
}
```

So for the same json response how to get data in typescript(Angular2).
I am very new to Angular2.Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript, it is the same as in Javascript, you use `JSON.parse(yourString)` to parse a JSON string, and `JSON.stringify` to transform your javascript object/array to a JSON string.

`JSON.parse` returns a plain object, so you can access its properties using dot notation (i.e. `myObject.myProperty`) or the array notation (i.e. `myObject['myProperty']`).

Cf [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse)

Comment: The OP was used to Java not JS

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript. That means that any valid Javascript is also valid Typescript.
Javascript has a global , built-in parser:

```js
let jsonString='{"hello": "World"}';

let myObject= JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(myObject.hello);
```

It also works on the other way:

```js
let obj= {
  key1: 1,
  key2: "Hi there",
  key3: new Date()
  }
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: The OP was used to Java not JS

Comment: So I explained how to do it with Javascript/Typescript, I don't see your point

Comment: My remarque wasn't about the answer by itself, but ' That means that any valid Javascript is also valid Typescript'. :) I mean the OP is not used to JS either probably